# Consulta retorna valor de outro usuário

Tags: java, sql, jsf, query, controller

Não estou conseguindo comparar o código (do profissional logado) com o codigoprofissionalcontratado (que deve ser o mesmo do profissional logado) na consulta sql e isso faz com que a consulta retorne um valor de outro profissional.

Segue abaixo o trecho do código:

```
FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
ELResolver resolver = context.getApplication().getELResolver();
LoginControllerOnline controller = new LoginControllerOnline();
controller = (LoginControllerOnline) 
resolver.getValue(context.getELContext(), null, "loginControllerOnline");
pessoa = controller.getPessoa();

if(pessoa instanceof Profissional) {
    Profissional profissional = (Profissional) pessoa;
    Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    String queryArtWeb = "SELECT aw.numeroart, aw.dataElaboracao, p.nome as nomeprofissional, pe.nome as nomeempresa, "
                + "(SELECT nome FROM IdentificacaoContratoArtWeb contrato WHERE contrato.numeroart=aw.numeroart and sequencialcontrato = 1 and sequencialidentificacao = 1) as nomecontratante, "
                + "t.idTipoArt, t.descricao as tipoArt, st.idSubtipoArt, st.descricao as subtipoArt, "
                + "aw.nomeProfissionalContratado, aw.nomeEmpresaContratada "
                + "FROM ArtWeb aw "
                + "LEFT JOIN pessoa p ON p.codigo = aw.codigoprofissionalcontratado "
                + "LEFT JOIN pessoa pe ON pe.codigo = aw.codigoempresacontratada "
                + "LEFT JOIN empresa e ON e.codigo = pe.codigo "
                + "LEFT JOIN TipoArt t ON t.idTipoArt = aw.tipoArt_idTipoArt "
                + "LEFT JOIN SubtipoArt st ON st.idSubtipoArt = aw.subtipoArt_idSubtipoArt "
                + "WHERE aw.codigoprofissionalcontratado = :codigo AND aw.databaixa IS NULL AND datapagamento IS NOT NULL OR valortaxa = 0";


    params.put("codigo", profissional.getCodigo());

    List<Object[]> registrosArtWeb = objectDao.listPesqQuery(queryArtWeb, params);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No `where` provavelmente faltam os parênteses em redor da cláusula `OR`.

```
WHERE   aw.codigoprofissionalcontratado = :codigo AND 
        aw.databaixa IS NULL AND 
        (datapagamento IS NOT NULL OR valortaxa = 0)
```

Comment: Era isso mesmo, pura falta de atenção. Obrigada!